# How to modify react useState from secondary File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm all new to react and am currently trying to modify an useState hook from another File. When one of the radio buttons from "Options.tsx" get's selected, the result should somehow be updated with the setResult function of useState hook so the  Tag gets updated.

I think I almost got it, but I don't manage to pass the correct 'onSelect' Property to Options.tsx so it is updated.

Here's my code so far:

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Result, ResultType } from './Result'
import { Options } from './Options'

function App() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState<ResultType>('pending')

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <Options onSelect={props.onSelect} />

                <Result result={result} />
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Options.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
    onSelect: (correct: boolean) => void
}

export const Options = ({onSelect}: Props) => {
    // TODO
    const setWrong = () => setResult('wrong');
    const setCorrect = () => setResult('correct');


    return(
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <input type='radio' id='option1' onSelect={setWrong}/>
                <label htmlFor='option1'>Label 1</label>
                <input type='radio' id='option2' onSelect={setCorrect}/>
                <label htmlFor='option2'>Label 2</label>
                <input type='radio' id='option3' onSelect={setCorrect}/>
                <label htmlFor='option3'>Label 3</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Result.tsx (just for completion - works fine so far)

```
import React from 'react'

export type ResultType = 'pending' | 'correct' | 'wrong'

interface Props {
    result: ResultType
}

export const Result = ({ result }: Props) => {
    switch (result) {
        case 'pending':
            return <h2>Make a guess</h2>
        case 'correct':
            return <h2>Yay, good guess!</h2>
        case 'wrong':
            return <h2>Nope, wrong choice...</h2>
    }
}
```

Any idea, how I can update the useState from Options.tsx?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple - you just need to propagate the setter via properties, to Options.

```
<Options setResult={setResult} />
```

Or, provide your own method which uses setResult, depending on circumstances.

I would note though that the value you're currently passing down to the onSelect, appears to be bound to an incorrect value. Typescript compiler is probably complaining about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the updater function to Options component:

```
<Options setResult={setResult} />
```

then in your Options Component you can use

```
props.setResult('blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `setResult` prop to Options component.

App.tsx:

```
function App() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState<ResultType>('pending')

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <Options onSelect={props.onSelect} setResult={setResult} />

                <Result result={result} />
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Options.tsx:

```
export const Options = ({onSelect, setResult}: Props) => {
    const setWrong = () => setResult('wrong');
    const setCorrect = () => setResult('correct');
    ...
}
```